# Как вернуть строку по умолчанию, если запрос вернул нольстрок?

Tags: sql-server

Запрос может вернуть строку или ноль строк, но при этом необходимо всегда выводить строку по умолчанию. Подскажите как это сделать?

```
select col1 as col1, col2 as col2 from table1 t1
where col1 like 'col'
group by t1.col1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если оригинальный запрос возвращает или одну, или ноль строк, то можно сделать примерно так:

```
select top 1 col1, col2 from 
(
    select 0 as SortOrder, col1 as col1, col2 as col2 from table1 t1
    where col1 like 'col'
    group by t1.col1
    union all  
    select 1 as SortOrder, 'col1default', 'col2default'
) as src
order by SortOrder
```

Comment: Да, именно это и нужно было, спасибо!

Comment: подскажите, всегда ли будет по умолчанию строчка `select 'col1default', 'col2default'` второй (не первой) если запрос вернёт строки?

Comment: @VladimirTsybin хороший вопрос, кстати :) на практике - скорее всего да. но строгой гарантии нет - сейчас подправлю ответ